# How can I perform a segue to a different tab in a UITabBarController when user selects a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITableViewCell` in the 1st tab of a `UITabBarController` that contains a list of things. When the user selects a cell, I'd like it to segue to a different tab in the `UITabBarController`.

I did it using the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
     performSegueWithIdentifier("PerformPlaylistsSegue", sender: self)

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

However, then problem is now, the bottom tab bar navigation is blocked.

I've found the following similar issues:

[How can I segue to the second tab of a tab bar controller from the first tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971114/how-can-i-segue-to-the-second-tab-of-a-tab-bar-controller-from-the-first-tab)

[Tab Bar Controller / Segue Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776197/tab-bar-controller-segue-issue)

Both posts have mentioning of it not being a good idea to segue to different tabs.

However, based on the purpose of my application, is there any way to force this to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided it's best not to mess with mother Xcode and put my `UITableView` in the ViewController where the segued tab is suppose to be, and not deal with the headache.